# Changing the value of dynamically created dropdowns

Tags: jquery

I have a list of drop-down elements dynamically created in my server side code.

```
<select id="color1">
<option value="blue">blue</option>
<option value="red">red</option>
<option value="green">green</option>
</select>
<select id="color2">
<option value="white">white</option>
<option value="orange">orange</option>
<option value="green">green</option>
</select>
<select id="color3">
<option value="black">black</option>
<option value="pink">pink</option>
<option value="brown">brown</option>
</select>
<select id="color4">
<option value="yellow">yellow</option>
<option value="black">black</option>
<option value="green">green</option>
</select>
```

I would require to write code in jQuery to change the value of all the SELECT values on a button click based on the selection of one of the SELECT elements.

For Eg: If I select red in the first SELECT, all the SELECT element value should be changed to red. If the value is already present in the target SELECTs, we just need to select the value, otherwise we need to append it.

Is it possible to write it in jQuery?

Comment: can you show us your html code ?

Comment: Sorry - I have edited and put the entire question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$selected = $('#color1 option:selected');
val = $selected.attr('value');
$('select:not(#color1)').each(function(i) {
   $opt = $('option[value='+val+']', $(this));
   if(!$opt.length) {
       $(this).append($selected).attr('selected', 'selected');
   } else {
       $opt.attr('selected', 'selected');
   }
});
```

Have not tested, though. Hope it's a good base to build on. Don't forget to attach it to the `select` event handler of the `#color1`, or to a `click` handler of a button of your choice.

Comment: Thanks pestaa. Can you please explain me this line - $t = $(el)

Comment: Oops, I have a typo in there. Hold on for a second. :)

Comment: So it was intended to be used a shortcut only, but apparently it wasn't needed that much anyway, so here we go. `$(this)` refers to the `select` DOM object in the current iteration and turns it into a jQuery object.

Comment: Great solution...thanks pestaa. Just one clarification $('select:not(#color1)').each(function(i)  - this would scan the entire DOM, right?

Comment: Correct. You can provide a comma-separated list of the IDs if you have specific requirements or type the container ID before the `select`.
On another note, I don't want to sound harsh, but if this snippet works for you, please accept my answer.

Comment: @John D By clicking the tick to the left of this block. That gives you 2 reputation and me 15. An upvote is worth 10 points to the receiver. Thank you very much and happy stackoverflowing! :)

Comment: @pestaa - sorry to disturb you again! Could you please explain this line?  $opt = $('option[value='+val+']', $(this)); Thanks.

Comment: @John `this` refers to the currently iterated `select` tag. It first is wrapped in a jQuery object for better handling (possibly not necessary, but this way it surely works), and searched for the specific `option` tag **within** it. To narrow any jQuery DOM search, you can pass the container item as the 2nd argument.